# Why void pointer would give different address than the one it is pointing to?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *pi = NULL;
    void *voidptr = pi;
    int num = 100;
    pi = &num;

    printf("%p\n",pi);
    printf("%p\n", voidptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Why would second printf give 0x0 but not same address as first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because assignment to one object won't affect another object in C and `voidptr` isn't updated since `pi`, whose value is `NULL` at that time, is assigned to it.

By the way, you invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`: You passed `int*` while `%p` expects `void*`.

Comment: One of the rare cases in C where casting to `void *` is actually required.

Comment: But pointers hold address ...voidptr is pointing to same address as pi ..no ?

Comment: `voidptr` *was* pointing to the same address as `pi`, but you updated only `pi`, so what they are pointing to are no longer same.

Comment: Oh i see the distinction now. Thank you !